# Algebraic Space in the sense of Serre.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I´m reading the paper of Serre *Espaces fibrés algebriqués* (Séminaire C.C 1958) and I have a question related to the definition of algebraic space. In the introduction of this paper, Serre says that the definition of an algebraic space is the one given in his *Faisceux algebriques coherents*, but I can not find a precise definition of this thing. Indeed I would like to know what we understand by an algebraic space in the language of schemes because in the above-mentioned article the theory of schemes was not developed and he worked with varieties instead.

Comment: He says that it means irreducible algebraic variety over $k$ on the first page of his paper *Espaces fibres algebriques*.

Comment: Indeed, I have just found that the schematic definition of algebraic variety in the sense of Serre is just an integral scheme of finite type